# iOS permissions for 3rd party app developers

Tags: ios, permissions

I am putting together a summary on iOS and Android security risks based on app permissions. On Android, it is easy to define all of the permissions and what 3rd party developers have access to (from the Android Manifest Permission page). On iOS, I have not been able to find a comprehensive list of what 3rd party developers can potentially access (maliciously or not).

For example, can iOS developers access data from the native iOS mail/calendar/contact applications? Does anyone have a link to a list of what can be accessed via the iOS APIs?

Thanks!

Comment: This is more of a question for an iOS dev forum.

Comment: The answer to your question could have security applications, but the question itself is an iOS API documentation question, not a security question.

Answer (score 0):

iOS has a relatively simple permissions system for applications.

Applications have no access to the mail application, but they can access data from the native calendar and contact applications, though only if this permission is enabled in-app, and can be disabled from the start menu:

[image]

So basically, they can access location, contacts, calendars, reminders, photos, bluetooth, microphone, motion activity, and various linked social media accounts (linked through the settings app), but only if the end user agrees to it, and this can be disabled. (I assume you're used to android, where the app can only be installed if all permissions are granted.)